# Google Analytics Content Experiments for non-simultaneous tests

Tags: google-analytics, a-b-testing, split-testing

I really like how Google Analytics displays the results of content experiments. However, it seems the tool only works for simultaneous tests. I'd like to use the tool without implementing the page variation code into my site.

For example, I want to test copy on an ecommerece category page. The original page variation would be the current page for the past 2500 visits. After making the copy changes, the new variation would be for the next 2500 visits.

I realize I can simply record the metrics before and after each variation, but I'd like to take advantage of Google's presentation of the experiment.

Is it possible to use the Content Experiments in this way?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, this is not possible (and essentially not an A-B test). It makes sense because there could be different reasons the first 2500 people visited your site, and therefore their behaviour could be different.

You could try looking in the advanced options of your experiment setup and turn "Distribute traffic evenly across all variations" On. At least going forward 50% of your traffic will go to your experiment page.